# Is it possible for particles to be accelerated FTL inside BH travelling towards the singularity?

Tags: black-hole

Maybe just maybe it is possible for a particle to travel FLT inside of black hole  because of the singularity gravitational force

This could be due to the fabric of space it self falling towards the singularity FTL beyond the event horizon. So technically 
A particle can go FTL moving with space itself not not moving through it, and this would break any laws of relativity

But if I'm wrong please tell me.

Comment: It looks like you are misguidedly conflating various unrelated theories. I don't think this is on topic here - it may be on Physics, but I think only as separate questions.

Comment: To start: singularity gravitational force - what do you mean? Particle turning to quark-gluon plasma, why? Particle going FTL how? 10 trillion degrees inside particle - what on earth? This just seems like unrelated, misunderstood words.

Comment: Omid: no, it isn't possible for a particle to be accelerated to faster than light inside a black hole. Or anywhere else.

Comment: Omit, your edit simply replaces one error with another. If you think of a particle and a photon travelling next to each other and in the same direction, **the particle cannot ever, under any circumstances, travel faster than the photon**; in fact, it can never even match the photon's speed. No distortion of spacetime can change this, not even in a BH. Extremely distant objects are moving away from us FTL because of the expansion of space, but that's very different, and doesn't apply at a local level. See [speed of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light) as a start.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little hard to follow the question.

The short answer is: No it doesn't move faster than light.

First off from the perspective of the outside observer, the particle doesn't reach the Schwartzchild radius, due to gravitational time dilation. From the viewpoint of the distant observer (the best kind to be when black holes are involved) the particle's clock slows to a stop as it nears the event horizon.

Your velocity is a relative and a local property, if you want to talk about the velocity you need to say what it is relative, and when black holes are involved you need to be careful about which metric you are measuring the velocity in. From the point of view of the infalling particle, it enters and crosses the event horizon. It may then be falling faster than the speed of light relative to people on the outside, but it is behind the event horizon, and can not return to them. It is not moving faster than light relative to any point which it can return to. So this doesn't break causality, nor does it allow for high-speed transport.

All that is certain is that in a short time (as the particle sees it) it will reach a singularity and then time and space will cease to exist for it, and all you are left with is mass.

Hadrons might become some kind of quark gluon plasma on their way in, but this doesn't make it lose mass, nor does it have any effect on the whether it moves faster or slower than light.

Comment: James: a particle can't slow to a stop as it nears the event horizon AND cross the event horizon. Especially since falling objects don't slow down. They fall faster and faster. Because the speed of light is getting slower and slower. See what Einstein said in 1920: _“As a simple geometric consideration shows, the curvature of light rays occurs only in spaces where the speed of light is spatially variable”._ We don't have GRBs for nothing.